# Empirical measurement of plant noise, for implementing Kalman Filter, using chirp data

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control

I want to implement a Kalman Filter for the system:
$$ \dot x = Ax + Bu + w_p, \qquad y = Cx + w_m $$
where $w_p$ and $w_m$ are the plant noise and measurement noise respectively, which are both white noise with covariance matrices
$$ E(w_p(t) w_p^T(t+\tau)) = S_p \delta(\tau), \qquad
   E(w_m(t) w_m^T(t+\tau)) = S_m \delta(\tau) .$$
Before I can implement the filter, I need to know $A$, $B$, $C$, $S_p$ and $S_m$.  I think I have figured out a way to do this empirically using chirp data.  I am interested in a reference to this kind of method, or any other method, for obtaining these matrices (and in particular the covariance matrices).

Comment: Based on what data do you want to estimate these parameters? Do you have complete data ($x$ and $y$ trajectories) or incomplete data (only $y$ trajectories)? It seems to me that a dot is missing in the observation equation.

Comment: Based upon knowledge of only $y$.  Also, where is the missing dot?

Comment: Since you said that measurement noise is $\delta$-correlated, your observations seem to be continuous-time. Another way to write this stochastic system is with Itô SDEs: $dX_t=AX_tdt+Bu_tdt+dW^{(p)}_t$, $dY_t=CX_tdt+dW^{(m)}_t$. Now things can be worked out using stochastic calculus. I can write an answer if this is indeed the measurement model you want to consider. If you want discrete-time measurements with Gaussian noise, it can work as well but the calculations will be different.

Comment: First, I'm not looking for a solution - I'm looking for a reference.  Second, there really isn't a dot in the second equation.  Google "continuous time Kalman filter" to see.

Comment: I'm asking for clarification because the mathematical literature on filtering considers a continuous-time observation model which is given by an SDE as in my previous comment. The notation you are using is seen in certain sources, but it is ambiguous and can be misleading for mathematical analysis. Another question: are you interested in online or offline estimation?

Comment: Yes, I can see that in your formulation, $Y$ is a continuous function, whereas is my formulation $y$ is a distribution, and so in some sense cannot be measured directly.  However, since one is the anti-derivative of the other, effectively the two formulations are equivalent.  Especially since my proposed solution involves taking the Fourier Transforms of the input and output data, and then taking the anti-derivative is simple dividing by $\omega$.

Comment: I am not totally familiar with the terminology online and offline.  I assume offline means that I collect a bunch of data, and then later at my leasure, do the analysis, whereas online means I try to do it on the fly.  If I am using the terminology correctly, then I want offline estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offline maximum-likelihood (ML) parameter estimation for continuous-continuous linear partially observed stochastic systems can be performed with the expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm.
The general EM algorithm is due to [1].
Ref [2] deals with the computations that have to be performed in order to use the EM algorithm for such a stochastic system (actually Ref [2] is more general as it deals with some classes of nonlinear problems as well).
Note that the noise covariances cannot be estimated with the ML approach, but are estimated separately from the quadratic variations. This is discussed in [2], Section IV.B.

[1] Dempster, A. P., Laird, N. M., & Rubin, D. B. (1977). Maximum Likelihood from Incomplete Data via the EM Algorithm. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological), 39(1), 1–22. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1977.tb01600.x

[2] Charalambous, C. D., & Logothetis, A. (2000). Maximum likelihood parameter estimation from incomplete data via the sensitivity equations: the continuous-time case. IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control, 45(5), 928–934. https://doi.org/10.1109/9.855553

Please also note that when only $y$ is observed, the model is not identifiable as multiple parameter combinations lead to the same $p(y)$. For example, a scaling in $x$ can be absorbed by an inverse scaling of $C$.

Comment: So far I have briefly looked at [1].  I need to wait for my library to send me [2], as I don't have electronic access.  Their method is completely different to my proposed method.